# Error when implementing Enums using Actionscript 3

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, enums

Ours is a Flex/Parsley/Blazeds/Spring project & I'm trying to implement java Enums in Actionscript3 and all I have to do is to send the Enum value to Spring service method.

The Java Enum Code (this is generated from XSD)

```
public enum ReferenceLookupType {
    PATIENT_VISIT_TYPE("PATIENT_VISIT_TYPE"), PATIENT_STATUS(
            "PATIENT_STATUS"), PATIENT_VISIT_INVALID_REASON(
            "PATIENT_VISIT_INVALID_REASON"), LIPID_PREFILLED_CODE(
            "LIPID_PREFILLED_CODE");

 private final String value;

    private ReferenceLookupType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    public static ReferenceLookupType convert(String value) {
        for (ReferenceLookupType inst : values()) {
            if (inst.toString().equals(value)) {
                return inst;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Actionscript Enum is:

```
package {

[Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="gov.hhs.cms.ehrds.datacollection.model.ReferenceLookupType")]
    public final class ReferenceLookupType {

        public static const PATIENT_VISIT_TYPE:ReferenceLookupType = new ReferenceLookupType("PATIENT_VISIT_TYPE");
        public static const PATIENT_STATUS:ReferenceLookupType = new ReferenceLookupType("PATIENT_STATUS");
        public static const PATIENT_VISIT_INVALID_REASON:ReferenceLookupType = new ReferenceLookupType("PATIENT_VISIT_INVALID_REASON");
        public static const LIPID_PREFILLED_CODE:ReferenceLookupType = new ReferenceLookupType("LIPID_PREFILLED_CODE");

private var _value:String;

        public function ReferenceLookupType(value:String) : void
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public function toString():String
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the mxml code:

```
[Bindable]
            private var refLookupType:ReferenceLookupType = ReferenceLookupType.LIPID_PREFILLED_CODE;


dispatcher(new ReferenceDataMessage(refLookupType, "RefData"));
```

The Error I'm getting is:

```
"Unable to create a new instance of type 'gov.hhs.cms.ehrds.datacollection.model.ReferenceLookupType'." faultCode="Client.Message.Encoding" faultDetail="Types cannot be instantiated without a public, no arguments constructor."


[RPC Fault faultString="Unable to create a new instance of type 'gov.hhs.cms.ehrds.datacollection.model.ReferenceLookupType'." faultCode="Client.Message.Encoding" faultDetail="Types cannot be instantiated without a public, no arguments constructor."]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:345]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:68]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:113]
    at NetConnectionMessageResponder/statusHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:609]
    at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/status()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\MessageResponder.as:264]
```

Can you please help in what I'm missing here and on how to implement Enums in Actionscript the right way.

Thanks

Harish

Answer (score 4):

Enums don't work out-of-the-box in Flex/BlazeDS.  You have to do a little custom magic.

The authoritative source on the topic is by far [this blog entry](http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2007/09/16/adding-enum-support-to-flex-amf-protocol) from Farrata Systems.

The main problem is that any object that is being sent across the wire must have a paramaterless constructor.  Enums break this rule.

So, you need to use a custom serializer / deserializer for Enums.

FWIW, I'd also suggest taking a look at [DTO2FX](http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2008/08/18/a-screencast-of-dto2fx-code-generator-of-dto-objects-for-flexjava-remoting) from the same crew.  They will generate the actionscript versions of your Java Enums correctly & automatically, to ensure that they can be sent across the wire without hiccups.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this...I came across this post earlier but was thinking there should be a simpler and easier way to do it......I will try that and let know..Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the easiest way I know of.